# How to implement VarIsNumeric in D5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have looked into D2009 sources but still I'm not sure how to *correctly* implement `VarIsNumeric` (Variants) function in Delphi 5 (there is no TVarType).

I'm using this for now:

```
function VarIsNumeric(const V: Variant): Boolean;
begin
  Result := VarType(V) in [varSmallInt, varInteger, varBoolean,
                           varByte,
                           varSingle,
                           varDouble];
end;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Was not varShortint, varWord, varLongWord and varCurrency part of the D5 variant type?

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be numeric. Why did you pick those and reject others? Look at each varXXX and make a judgement. If you want you definition to match the D2009 rtl, use that as your template. It looks like you have all you need to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, in XE8, varDate is not considered a numeric value for example.

Comment: @LURD The asker can make his own mind up surely

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes but by "correctly" I would assume to follow how it is implemented now.

Comment: @LURD, There is no "arShortint, varWord, varLongWord" in D5

Comment: @zig But their values are well know, and can easily be defined in your code. I hope my answer explains it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing the value returned by `VarType()` is the correct approach. You just need to decide which types are numeric. Delphi 5 has very different variant support from later versions. Indeed, Delphi 6 made great changes in this area.

The var types define in the Delphi 5 system unit are:

```
{ Variant type codes (wtypes.h) }
varEmpty    = $0000; { vt_empty       }
varNull     = $0001; { vt_null        }
varSmallint = $0002; { vt_i2          }
varInteger  = $0003; { vt_i4          }
varSingle   = $0004; { vt_r4          }
varDouble   = $0005; { vt_r8          }
varCurrency = $0006; { vt_cy          }
varDate     = $0007; { vt_date        }
varOleStr   = $0008; { vt_bstr        }
varDispatch = $0009; { vt_dispatch    }
varError    = $000A; { vt_error       }
varBoolean  = $000B; { vt_bool        }
varVariant  = $000C; { vt_variant     }
varUnknown  = $000D; { vt_unknown     }
                     { vt_decimal $e  }
                     { undefined  $f  }
                     { vt_i1      $10 }
varByte     = $0011; { vt_ui1         }
                     { vt_ui2     $12 }
                     { vt_ui4     $13 }
                     { vt_i8      $14 }
{ if adding new items, update varLast, BaseTypeMap and OpTypeMap }
varStrArg   = $0048; { vt_clsid    }
varString   = $0100; { Pascal string; not OLE compatible }
varAny      = $0101;
varTypeMask = $0FFF;
varArray    = $2000;
varByRef    = $4000;
```

In modern Delphi `VarIsNumeric` is implemented as

```
Result := VarTypeIsOrdinal(AVarType) or VarTypeIsFloat(AVarType);
```

and in turn

```
function VarTypeIsOrdinal(const AVarType: TVarType): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AVarType in [varSmallInt, varInteger, varBoolean, varShortInt,
                         varByte, varWord, varLongWord, varInt64, varUInt64];
end;

function VarTypeIsFloat(const AVarType: TVarType): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AVarType in [varSingle, varDouble, varCurrency];
end;
```

Now, there is nothing mystical about `TVarType` in modern Delphi. It is just an alias to `Word`:

```
type
  TVarType = Word;
```

So you can certainly implement `VarIsNumeric` in the manner you propose in the question. The only point for debate is which var types to test for. To follow modern Delphi, you would test for these types:

```
varSmallInt
varInteger
varBoolean
// varShortInt
varByte
// varWord
// varLongWord
// varInt64
// varUInt64
varSingle
varDouble
varCurrency
```

I've commented out the values that are not defined by the Delphi 5 RTL.

If you were expecting to receive variants from sources that might use some of these types, then you might care to define the missing values, and test for them. The missing values are:

```
varShortInt = $0010; { vt_i1          16 }
varWord     = $0012; { vt_ui2         18 }
varLongWord = $0013; { vt_ui4         19 }
varInt64    = $0014; { vt_i8          20 }
varUInt64   = $0015; { vt_ui8         21 }
```